# React hooks async useEffect to load database data

Tags: reactjs

I'm using async useEffect in React because I need to do database requests. Then, add this data to my `react-charts-2`

```
const [ plSnapShot, setPlSnapShot ] = useState({
   grossIncome: 0.00,
   opeExpenses: 0.00,
   nonOpeExpenses: 0.00,
   netIncome: 0.00,
   grossPotencialRent: 0.00,
   lastMonthIncome: 0.00
});

const [ thisMonthPayment, setThisMonthPayments ] = useState({
    labels: [],
    data: [],
    color: 'blue'
});


useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        await axios.get(`${url.REQ_URL}/home/getUserFullName/${userID}`)
            .then(async (res) => {
                setUserFullName(res.data);

                await axios.get(`${url.REQ_URL}/home/getThisMonthPayments/${propertyID}`)
                    .then(async (resMonthPay) => {
                        let total = 0;
                        let obj = {
                            labels: [],
                            data: [],
                            color: 'blue'
                        };
                        const data = resMonthPay.data;
                        for(const d of data) {
                            obj.labels.push(helper.formatDate(new Date(d.date)));    
                            obj.data.push(d.amount);
                            total += d.amount;
                        }
                        setThisMonthPayments(obj);
                        setTotalEarnedMonth(parseFloat(total));

                        await axios.get(`${url.REQ_URL}/home/plSnapshot/${propertyID}`)
                            .then(async (resPL) => {
                                const data = resPL.data;
                                setPlSnapShot({
                                    grossIncome: parseFloat(data.GrossIncome || 0).toFixed(2),
                                    opeExpenses: parseFloat(data.OperatingExpenses || 0).toFixed(2),
                                    nonOpeExpenses: parseFloat(data.NonOperatingExpenses || 0).toFixed(2),
                                    netIncome: parseFloat(data.NetIncome || 0).toFixed(2),
                                    grossPotencialRent: parseFloat(data.GrossPotencialRent || 0).toFixed(2),
                                    lastMonthIncome: parseFloat(data.LastMonthIncome || 0).toFixed(2)
                                });
                            });
                    });
            });
    }
    fetchData();
}, [propertyID, userID]);

const pieChart = {
    chartData: {
        labels: ['Gross Income', 'Operating Expenses', 'Non Operating Expenses'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [plSnapShot.grossIncome, plSnapShot.opeExpenses, plSnapShot.nonOpeExpenses],
            backgroundColor: [
                ChartConfig.color.primary,
                ChartConfig.color.warning,
                ChartConfig.color.info
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: [
                ChartConfig.color.primary,
                ChartConfig.color.warning,
                ChartConfig.color.info
            ]
        }]
    }
};

const horizontalChart = {
    label: 'Last Month Income',
    labels: ['Gross Potencial Rent', 'Last Month Income'],
    chartdata: [plSnapShot.grossPotencialRent, plSnapShot.lastMonthIncome]
};
```

Here is an example of how I call the Chart component in my code in the render/return method.

```
<TinyPieChart
   labels={pieChart.chartData.labels}
   datasets={pieChart.chartData.datasets}
   height={110}
   width={100}
/>
```

And my Pie Chart component is just to display it

```
import React from 'react';
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';

// chart congig
import ChartConfig from '../../Constants/chart-config';

const options = {
    legend: {
        display: false,
        labels: {
            fontColor: ChartConfig.legendFontColor
        }
    }
};

const TinyPieChart = ({ labels, datasets, width, height }) => {
    const data = {
        labels,
        datasets
    };
    return (
        <Pie height={height} width={width} data={data} options={options} />
    );
}

export default TinyPieChart;
```

Mostly of the times it works just fine, but sometimes the chart data is loaded and displayed in the screen real quick, then it disappear and the chart is displayed empty (no data). Am I loading it properly with the useEffect or should I use another method?

Thanks you.

Comment: Can you more precisely define "sometimes"? Sometimes as in on page load? On some specific action on the page (e.g. button click, etc.). Just randomly without you touching anything?

Comment: Yes, when it loads. And yes, without touching anything.

Comment: I was wondering if I should use ```useCallBack```, but honestly, I don't know well how it works.

Comment: Post the return method of your main component. The one with the `useEffect`.

Comment: @codemonkey It has a lot of code there. Just html tags and calling components. I posted the part of the code that call the chart: ```TinyPieChart```

Comment: The reason the chart is flashing is because on first render, there is no data in `thisMonthPayment`. So you need to add a condition to your return method to either not render anything until `thisMonthPayment` has some data in it or show a loader while `useEffect` is doing its thing. Since you declined to post the code, I cannot tell you exactly how to do that, but you probably get the idea anyway.

Comment: @codemonkey Thank you. I got it. I think the best solution for me is a Loader because sometimes it's possible that ```thisMonthPayment``` is empty. If you want to post the answer with a ```const [ loader, setLoader ] = useState(false)``` then change it to true when the useEffect is done, I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The momentary flashing is likely due to the fact that the chart data is empty on first render. So depending on the time it take for your `useEffect` to fetch the data, that flashing may present a real problem.

One common solution is to use a state variable to indicate that the data is being loaded and either not display anything in place of the chart or display a loaded of some sort. So you can add something like you suggested in the comments `const [ loader, setLoader ] = useState(true)`. Then once the data is loaded, togged it to `false`.

Meanwhile, inside your render function, you would do:

```
...
...
{loader ? 
   <div>Loading....</div>
 :
   <TinyPieChart
    labels={pieChart.chartData.labels}
    datasets={pieChart.chartData.datasets}
    height={110}
    width={100}
   />

}
```

`loader` can go from true to false or vise versa, depending on what make more intuitive sense to you.